# String comparison does not work in Shell

Tags: linux, shell, conditional-statements

I'm pretty new to shell programming languages. Why does the following code echo false after printing "File or directory not found."?

```
#!/bin/sh -xu
ARG_PATH="/srv/path/to/Something"

if ["$ARG_PATH" = "/srv/path/to/Something"] 
then 
   echo "true!" 
else
   echo "false!"
fi
```

I've tried running the code in sh and bash, doesn't really change anything.

Answer (score 2):

check whether path is correct or not ? your syntax is seems okay except `Bash` is space sensitive give the `space` after `[` and before `]`

```
ARG_PATH="/srv/path/to/Something"

if [ $ARG_PATH = "/srv/path/to/Something" ]
then
        echo $? #display 0 if both r same
fi
```

Comment: yes, thank you I did not expect that

Answer (score 1):

Put spaces around the bracket, if you don't the shell will think `["$ARG_PATH"` is the command when it should be `[`.

The correct test thus is `if [ "$ARG_PATH" = "/srv/path/to/Something" ]`

Comment: thank you for the quick reply, but that doesn't change anything. I looked this up and read that in Bourne Shell string comparison is done using =, but apparently the shell is trying to evaluate the string as a path or something like that?

Comment: Note the spaces around the `[` and `]`

Comment: While bash will tolerate `==` inside `[...]`, the [standard POSIX syntax](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) uses just `=` to compare strings. (This differs from the syntax for the non-POSIX extension `[[...]]`.)

Comment: That's true. Updated my answer to reflect that :)

Comment: `[ ]` is not a syntax element, it is a command. Therefore needs separating spaces.